# What is the difference between (int *)array, (int *)&array, and &array in a pointer assignment?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have 3 lines of code that performs exactly the same but have different syntax, the base code being:

```c
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter the size of your array [a][b]: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    int arr[a][b];

    int *pa;

    pa = (int *)&arr;
     
    for (i = 0; i < a*b; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] [%d] = ", i/b, i%b);
        scanf("%d", (pa + i));
    }
```

On the line `pa = (int *)&arr;`, I can switch that line to `(int *)array`, `(int *)&array`, and `&array` without encountering any issues, only experiencing a warning at the last one. I was wondering the correct syntax is and the difference between all 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Two key tidbits:

1. The address of an array is the address of its first element.
2. When treated as a pointer, an array degrades into a pointer to its first element

So,

1. ```c
   pa = arr;
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```c
   pa = &(arr[0]);   // Type mismatch: RHS is int (*)[b]
   ```

   You use a typecast to silence the error when doing `pa = (int *)arr;`.
2. ```c
   pa = &arr;
   ```

   is equivalent to

   ```c
   pa = &(arr[0]);   // Type mismatch: RHS is int (*)[b]
   ```

   You use a typecast to silence the error when doing `pa = (int *)&arr;`.

These typecasts are not safe. If you want to treat it as a 1d array of `int` values, best to declare it that way too.

Answer (score 0):

- The correct syntax is `pa = &arr[0];` and if you find yourself in need to add a cast, you are doing something wrong. Bluntly put, if you are a beginner, you shouldn't be casting pointers ever.
- `pa = &arr` does not "only give a warning", it's invalid C. This is a so-called constraint violation - invalid assignment of non-compatible pointer types. Please study [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565) and [What must a C compiler do when it finds an error?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277340)
- Similarly, `pa = (int *)&array` is an invalid pointer conversion between non-compatible types. It will compile but has a compiler-specific outcome. It's strictly speaking incorrect code but may work for the specific compiler and system.
- `pa = (int *)array` is wrong for similar reasons too - since `array` has decayed into a pointer to array type which is not compatible with `int*`.

Comment: If I simply do pa = arr; it gives me an "[Error] assignment from incompatible pointer type". When I asked my teacher about it, that is what he showed me. How do I simply fix that with my base code above?

Comment: @MinhNguyen Ah my bad, I didn't notice it was a 2D array. Will update the answer.

Comment: Thankies,will make a note of that for next time I do somethin like that